# Adding a result column with conditions from other table

Tags: mysql, select

I'm selecting everything from my `players` table, then I want to check if player `id` or player `name` is set in other table with an condition.

I got two tables - `players` and `shop`.

`shop` has the following columns: `uid`, `dateline`, `from`, `done`.

As I said, I'm selecting everything from `players` table, now I want to add additional column to the result called `was_shopping` and it will be the `1` when `players`.`id` or `players`.`name` is somewhere in the `shop` and where `shop`.`dateline` is higher than my variable given.

Just to be sure you understood everything correctly it should goes like this (its not a query, its just a word-example on how it should works in query):

```
SELECT *
FROM players
WHERE (players.id OR players.name)
IN (
    SELECT `uid` AND `from`
    FROM `shop`
    WHERE `dateline` >= xxxxx
   )
```

And if `players`.`id` or `players`.`name` will be inside of the `shop`.`uid` OR `shop`.`from` with `dateline >= xxxxx` it should add another column to the result: `was_shopping` - `1` OR `0` (if was found in `shop` table then 1, and 0 in case if not found).

Please post a comment if you don't understand a word.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.*, case when s.uid is null then 0 else 1 end as was_shopping
From players as p
left join shop as s
where s.uid = p.id and s.dateline > = xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I believe this will return the correct results. Note I am using a value of 10 for dateline selection :

```
select p.*, case when s.uid is null then 0 else case when dateline>10 then 1 else 0 end end as was_shopping 
from players p
left join shops s
on p.id = s.uid or p.name like concat('%',`from`,'%')
where s.uid is not null
```

Comment: The problem is that I can not left join it on `p.id = s.uid` because `p.id` is totally different than `s.uid`, so it should just check if there is an shops `uid` or `from` with same values as players `id` or `name`.

Comment: What are the data-types of id, uid, name and from?

Comment: `id` is `int(11)`, `uid` is `int(11)`, `name` is `varchar(255)` and `from` is `varchar(255)`.

Comment: Some data would be helpful. Have you tried running the SQL I provided?